# HTML5 Canvas ability to zoom in/out after drawing images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, zooming

My app is based on users placing images on a canvas (via functions I created that use lineTo(), and arc() to create complicated shapes) and then letting them zoom out so get a higher-level picture of what they've done. Similarly they can load somebody else's creation and zoom-in to see at a lower level what all these objects looks like in more detail.

Is this possible? When I think zoom, I'm thinking google-maps type zoom.

If it's not possible, are there other solutions, like using regular images and re-sizing part of the page?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is what you are thinking of: [`scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations#Scaling).

```
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(2,2);    //zoom-in
doMyComplexShape();
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that for every zoom I'll have to comletely redraw the shapes? EDIT - of course I'll have to remove the old shapes

Comment: That seems inefficient if I have hundreds of objects in the canvas. How does something like google maps do this? Also, for what I'm trying to do would you said it's better to work with drawing objects manually via lineTo() and arc() or use small .png images? Thanks.

Comment: @YoungMoney - Google Maps is not using `<canvas>` to draw the maps. They used images right in the DOM, and use CSS to move them around. PS: Redrawing canvas is very fast in browsers. This is what "animation" means - constantly changing pictures. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial%3ABasic_animations).

Comment: Thanks a lot Derek you've been very helpful. I'll keep going along with my present approach and redraw as I need to. Just out of curiosity, the browser would utilize the GPU extensively for a task like this right?

Comment: @JDS - Some browsers have GPU-accelerated rendering.